# Find Total from label in listview on checkbox clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a row in `listview` in which I have the package cost. What I have to do is whichever checkbox is clicked, the package cost of that row will be summed up and shown in the textbox that's outside the `listview`.  I have no idea what to write - I have only this code but I don't know how to calculate it:

```
ArrayList em = new ArrayList();
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chkselect = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    Label lblcost = (Label)row.FindControl("Label5");
    if (chkselect.Checked)
    {
        em.Add(lblcost.Text);
    }
}
```

This what I have done when I'm doing mailing with checkbox

Comment: Hi Kamna, welcome to [so].  Could you please refrain from using text speak?  It makes your posts really hard to read, discouraging people from reading them.  This time, I've edited your post to make it more readable, but it would be much appreciated if you would post in a more "proper" manner next time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sum the cost in `variable` and you probably do not need `ArrayList` for this. You can assign the calculated total cost to `Text` property of `TextBox`

```
int total = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chkselect = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    Label lblcost = (Label)row.FindControl("Label5");
    if (chkselect.Checked)
    {         
        total += double.Parse(lblcost.Text);
    }
}
textBoxCost.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: its wrking thanks for ur help bt i hv to do this code on button click can we do that when we jst checked the checkbox the total will automatically shown in textbox and if we unchecked the checkbox the cost will be deducted from the total

Comment: You will need to put this code in CheckedChanged event, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx

Comment: bt i hv these checkboxes in listview's item tempalte then how to use this event cn u plz expalin.. thx

Comment: You can add RowCommand event, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast `label.Text` to decimal.

```
decimal total = 0;
decimal value = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chkselect = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    Label lblcost = (Label)row.FindControl("Label5");
    if (chkselect.Checked)
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(lblcost.Text, out value))
        {
            total += value;
        }
    }
}
```

I used here safer why in case when input was not numeric.